# javascript inserting content from a div to another div

Tags: javascript, html

I've got 2 divs:

```
<div id="a">
<div>html</div>
<script>javascript</script>
</div>

<div id="b">
</div>
```

I'm getting the content from a div and inserting it into the `b` div using this:

```
var imgCont = document.getElementById('a').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('b').innerHTML = imgCont;
```

The problem is that it's copying only the HTML, without scripts, but I need the scripts to be copied. I know that the line `var imgCont = document.getElementById('a').innerHTML;` gets the HTML and the scripts correctly (I just tested it by inserting `alert(imgCont);`) but the second line is not inserting the scripts. Maybe I should use something instead of `innerHTML`? Or maybe it's harder than I thought? Can anybody please help me?

EDIT:

Ok, so i think the problem is somewhere else... I'm giving you the whole page, because i'm really confused...

```
<?php
require "setup.php";

$nameGet = $_GET['Result'];

$page = $_GET['pg'];
if(empty($page)){ 
$page = 0;
} 
$urlGet="SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id='$nameGet'";
$theUrl=mysql_query($urlGet);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($theUrl, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $mp4 = "{$row['mp4']}";
    $ogg = "{$row['ogg']}";
};
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Scoopoly</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="res/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="res/plugins/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="res/plugins/video-js/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="res/plugins/video-js/video.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var pg = <?php echo $page ?>;
var vid = new Boolean;
var setup = new Boolean;
function start() {
setup = false;
swichtoV();
}
function swichtoV() {
    var swichV = document.getElementById('swichV');
    var swichI = document.getElementById('swichI');
    swichV.style.fontSize = "70px";
    swichV.style.marginTop = "0px";
    swichV.style.marginLeft = "25px";
    swichI.style.fontSize = "40px";
    swichI.style.marginTop = "18px";
    swichI.style.marginRight = "54px";
    var vidCont = document.getElementById('vidList').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('slidesContainer').innerHTML = vidCont;
    vid = true;
    slideshow();
}

function swichtoI() {
    vid = false;
    slideshow();
    var swichV = document.getElementById('swichV');
    var swichI = document.getElementById('swichI');
    swichV.style.fontSize = "40px";
    swichV.style.marginTop = "18px";
    swichV.style.marginLeft = "60px";
    swichI.style.fontSize = "70px";
    swichI.style.marginTop = "0px";
    swichI.style.marginRight = "12px";
    var imgCont = document.getElementById('imgList').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('slidesContainer').innerHTML = imgCont;
    vid = true;
    slideshow();
}
var currentPosition;
function slideshow(){
    if (!setup) {
  currentPosition = pg;
  setup = true;
    } else {
currentPosition = 0;
    }
  var cPos = (currentPosition * 720) * -1;
  var slideWidth = 720;
  var slideHold = document.getElementById('vidList');
var slides = $('div#slidesContainer div.slide');
  var numberOfSlides = slides.length;

  // Remove scrollbar in JS
  $('#slidesContainer').css('overflow', 'hidden');

  // Wrap all .slides with #slideInner div
  slides
    .wrapAll('<div id="slideInner"></div>')
    // Float left to display horizontally, readjust .slides width
    .css({
      'float' : 'left',
      'width' : slideWidth,
    });
  // Set #slideInner width equal to total width of all slides
  $('div#slidesContainer div#slideInner').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);
  $('div#slidesContainer div#slideInner').css('margin-left', cPos);
    // Insert controls in the DOM
  $('.control').remove();
  $('#slideshow')
    .prepend('<a class="control" id="leftControl"></a><a class="control" id="rightControl"></a>')

  // Hide left arrow control on first load
  manageControls(currentPosition);

  // Create event listeners for .controls clicks
  $('.control')
    .bind('click', function(){
    // Determine new position
    currentPosition = ($(this).attr('id')=='rightControl') ? currentPosition+1 : currentPosition-1;
    pg = ($(this).attr('id')=='rightControl') ? pg+1 : pg-1;
    // Hide / show controls
    manageControls(currentPosition);
    // Move slideInner using margin-left
    $('#slideInner').animate({
      'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)
    });
  });

  // manageControls: Hides and Shows controls depending on currentPosition
  function manageControls(position){
    // Hide left arrow if position is first slide
    if(position==0){ $('#leftControl').hide() } else{ $('#leftControl').show() }
    // Hide right arrow if position is last slide
    if(position==numberOfSlides-1){ $('#rightControl').hide() } else{ $('#rightControl').show() }
  }
};
</script>
</head>

<body class="visuals" onload="start()">
<div id="bHoldera">
<a class="wBa" href="web.php">web</a>
<a class="aBa" href="audio.php">audio</a>
<a class="vBa" href="visuals.php">visuals</a>

</div>
<?php
if((!empty($mp4))&&(!empty($ogg))){
    echo "
    <video id='my_video_1' class='video-js vjs-default-skin' controls
  preload='auto' width='700' height='350'
  data-setup='{}'>
  <source src='res/videos/mp4/$mp4' type='video/mp4'>
  <source src='res/videos/ogg/$ogg' type='video/ogg'>
</video>
";
}
else {
echo "<video id='my_video_1' class='video-js vjs-default-skin' controls
  preload='auto' width='700' height='350'
  data-setup='{}'>
  <source src='res/videos/mp4/my_video.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
  <source src='res/videos/ogg/my_video.ogg' type='video/ogg'>
</video>";  
}
?>

<div id="videoDiv">
</div>
<div id="swichHolder">
<a class="swichB" id="swichV" onclick="swichtoV()">Videos</a>
<div id="cross"></div>
<a class="swichB" id="swichI" onclick="swichtoI()">Images</a>
</div>
<div id="menu">

<div id="slideshow">
    <div id="slidesContainer">

</div>
</div>

</div>
<div id="vidList" style="display:none;">
<?php
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY date";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1);

$i = 0;
echo '<div class="slide"><table id="menuT">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
    if ($i == 3){
        echo '</table></div><div class="slide"><table>';
        $i = 0;
    }
    echo "<td id='menutd'>
<a class='menuLink' class='VV".$row['id']."'>
<div id='II".$row['id']."' style='width: 230px;
height: 136px;
background: url(res/videos/img/".$row['img'].");
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:center;'></div>
</a>
</td>
<script type='text/javascript'>
.VV".$row['id'].".onclick = function() {
var Result = '".$row['id']."';
location.href='visuals.php?Result=' + Result + '&pg=' + pg;
     }
</script>
";
    $i++;
}
echo '</table></div>';
?>
</div>
<div id="imgList" style="display:none;">
<?php
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY date";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);

$i = 0;
echo '<div class="slide"><table id="menuT">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){
    if ($i == 3){
        echo '</table></div><div class="slide"><table>';
        $i = 0;
    }
    echo "<td id='menutd'>
<a class='menuLink' id='VVi".$row['id']."'>
<div id='IIi".$row['id']."' style='width: 230px;
height: 136px;
background: url(res/images/".$row['image'].");
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:center;'></div>
</a>
</td>
<script type='text/javascript'>
VVi".$row['id'].".onclick = function() {
    alert('yes');
var Result = '".$row['id']."';
location.href='visuals.php?Result=' + Result + '&pg=' + pg;
     }
</script>
";
    $i++;
}
echo '</table></div>';
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems to be working, check this: http://jsfiddle.net/7Qwaj/

Comment: What do you mean by "scripts"?

Comment: I recommend either using Firefox with Firebug plugin or Google Chrome and the Developer Tools to see the Javascript errors (if any). They both also allow you to step through the javascript code line by line. I use it everyday, and it makes debugging problems like this so fast.

Comment: Are you trying to apply values to `div` elements? Because that's a completely different question. `<script>` tags are always in the `window` context, no matter what element they're nested in.

Comment: Are you creating elements with duplicate ids? (Because you had unique ids originally but then when you copy the elements the copies have the same ids?)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it (no using `innerHTML`, hurray!):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <style>
            </style>

    </head>
    <body>


        <div id="a">
            <div>html</div>
            <script>alert("you'll only see this once")</script>
        </div>

        <div id="b">
        </div>

        <script>


            function whoAmI(el) {
                alert("I'm element " + el.getAttribute("id"));
            }



            var a = document.getElementById("a");
            var b = document.getElementById("b");

            for(var i = 0, l = a.childNodes.length; i < l; i++) {
                b.appendChild(a.childNodes[i].cloneNode(true));
            }


            console.log(a);
            console.log(b);


            whoAmI(a);
            whoAmI(b);


        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Also, I'm pretty sure duplicating a script tag will not execute its contents. You would need to do that manually somehow.

Edit: I updated the code so that you could identify the different div elements (assuming that's what you wanted to do).

Comment: @JaredFarrish is that just for reference or did I make a glaring error in my code? :)

Comment: No, I just wanted to add the reference in case someone wanted to review it. `:)`